# Several domains using 302 redirect to our domain

Tags: seo, domains, redirects, best-practices, 302-redirect

I am wondering what implications we can run into if one of our dealers is redirecting several of their domains using a 302 to our domain. The reason they are doing this is because they want to have time to build on their current sites but still want some content on the domains they own.

Currently our domain is under a Manual Penalty for back links that we are working on removing. I do not like the idea of them linking back to our site but I need logical reasons other than "because I don't want you to".

Answer (score 1):

If they want content on the sites they own they should put unique content on it. One page is enough. Much better than 302ing to your site.

Comment: I agree. A one page site can be quite effective. I have a one page site that seems to be performing rather well. People are driving several hundred miles to participate in our sales. Having domains redirect to your site may/may not hurt you, but it is not a good idea from an SEO perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Just think about the customer...

A one page, dedicated site with information about each dealer is going to please visitors/customers more so than them simply redirecting to your general site.

When I put it in that context, it's easy to understand that they should have a one-page site as a 'make do' rather than a 301 redirect.